# navigate to the second vc at the end of the animated view without using a button

Tags: ios, swift

How can i navigate to the second vc at the end of the animated view without using a button?

I have watched some tutorials but in each videos they are solving this problem by using a button...

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `performSegueWithIdentifier` in your completion block as below

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

 //your animations

}, completion: {

// your segue, for example
//self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signInView", sender: self)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this code

After your animation:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoSecondVC" sender:self];
```

and override this method in your current first vc:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

{

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"GoSecondVC"])
{
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    YourSecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
    [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
}
```

}